# RTC UPS power cycle on low battery

Tags: ups, low-battery, battery-monitor

My RTC UPS switches on and off the whole time when the battery is low.
I think it could be with the voltage monitor circuit as with the led indicator on the ups it shows the ups's battery voltage is full.

So if the ups dies the battery voltage rises a little bit because the load is removed and then the ups thinks the capacity is so that it can run again.

Can someone please advice me if my assumptions are correct and for what type of problem I could be looking for to repair on the circuit board.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are reasonable, but one has to do some measurements in order to confirm them.

Looks like your UPS is a very bad design or broken in one way or another.

A sane UPS should not restart after entering in a "low battery shutdown" state.

It is even more important that the UPS would not start when powered from the battery side and no explicit "start" command is applied. Otherwise, one will not be able to safely replace the battery pack.

Comment: You don't know for what type of circuit I'm looking for in order to see if there could be a broken component?